# PC freezes when pressing PrintScreen

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, freeze

Today I noticed that my PC freezes when I press <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>. Interestingly, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> does not have that effect.

The last things I remember

- I uninstalled Steam
- some Windows Updates were installed
- Adobe Reader updated on 2016-10-12
- Silverlight updated on 2016-10-12
- I updated bvckup2 on 2016-10-14

I've never installed any tools that would change the behavior of <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>, since I'm quite happy with the default Windows behavior.

I have tried:

- closing all tray icons, without any effect
- rebooting (well, after it freezed, I had to)

System information:

- Windows 7 SP1 x64
- AMD Radeon HD 7700 (Driver 21.19.137.1)
- NVIDIA Geforce 8400 GS (Driver 9.18.13.4144)

I can provide any other system info if needed.

How do I best start investigating this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the [answers at Microsoft](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/print-screen-causing-computer-to-freeze/7fb01905-2e7c-49ab-b09f-b00a4c22e65c) helped me:

> System Configuration - Boot - Advanced options - deselect Debug

Comment: Worked, thanks. I installed Windbg shortly before the problem appeared; maybe it switched on debug.